# Fetching the public status messages of users on Facebook, in a certain area, without logging in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am coding a facebook app which aims to fetch all the public status messages/checkin places of users falling in a particular range/area.
I can provide facebook with latitude-longitude pair, a range and expect it to return status messages of people in the area matching the latitude-longitude pair and the range.

Is it possible through Graph-API or FQL?
I can consider both.

till now I have zeroed my search on facebook 'search' API, but am not sure whether it does the above things.

One more thing I am worried about is the need of logging in.
I want to search the things which are publicly available, while my users don't have to log in to their facebook accounts.

I searched Google with few keywords to see what kind of data facebook makes available to third parties publicly, and I can only get results of pages and groups.

Can't I get Users's messages publicly!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that Facebook won't let me pull data publicly, at least as of now, and will require users to sign in and provide specific permissions, which I have specified, to my app.

Comment: Since now Facebook has made the statuses go Public (by user's consent), public statuses can be searched: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching